# Render a template with a specific status code

Tags: php, symfony, partial, http-status-codes

Since I've read that Chrome is having trouble looping an HTML5 video if the response code isn't 206, I'd like to render my template with a 206 code.

Yet I've not found anywhere how to specify an html code when rendering a template... Did anyone already tried that and succeeded ?

Comment: I don't know why that's different but that problem solved itself when I put my app into test/prod env.
Suddenly, the video is looping as it should.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the controller you can create and return a Response object with the content and the specified return code, as example:

```
return new Response(
    $this->renderView('AcmeDemoBundle:Default:video.html.twig', array(
            'param1'    => $param1,
            'param2'     => $param2,
        )),
        206  // return code
);
```

Hope this help

Comment: This indeed works syntactically. I can see in the dev tool bar that the response status is indeed 206 but I still have that "HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date:          Thu, 05 Mar 2015 18:45:02 GMT" just under my <body> element when I inspect the source code with chrome's tool... Does it have any incidence ?

Comment: I'm also getting this header prepended to the response body

Comment: Hi @PierredeLESPINAY have you tried in the (sf) prod environment? check the author comment on the question itself. Let me know

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a response object with your renderResponse that has the necessary status code.

```
$response = new Response('', 206);

return $this->renderResponse(
// Or return $this->container->get('templating')
    'AcmeBundle:Video:show.html.twig',
    array('video' => video),
    $response
);
```

If you do not pass in a `Response` with your renderResponse one will be generated automatically. If you pass one then it's content is just set to that of the rendered template (as you can see in [the code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/8d1265216260c464b5de132c90c218c9dbd4690e/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/TwigEngine.php#L86-L100))

Comment: This should be the correct answer. You can also use the `render` method directly: `public function render($view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null)`. So the call would be: `return $this->render('AcmeBundle:Video:show.html.twig', array('video' => video), new Response('', 206));`

Answer (score 4):

New implementation

```
protected function renderError(array $parameters, $statusCode = 500)
{
    return $this->render(
        'default/error.html.twig',
        $parameters,
        new Response('', $statusCode)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I you at this before you are rendering the template you will get the desired result:

```
$this->getContext()->getResponse()->setStatusCode(206);
```

btw.
The class `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` provides constants for all valid HTTP-states