# How can I access flash messages in Symfony's custom error controller? (Or at least pass information from normal controller to error controller))

Tags: php, symfony, session, flash-message, custom-error-handling

I would like to access to flash message in custom `framework.error_controller` in Symfony (5.4).

I have a HomeController where I set this:

```php
$request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->set('info','This is a test')
dump($request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->all());
throw new BadRequestException("error.bad.request.accueil");
```

Of course here the `dump` works fine.

Here is a part of `framework.yaml`:

```yaml
framework:
  error_controller: App\Controller\CommonOffice\ErrorController::show
```

And here is the show function for the ErrorController

```php
public function show(\Throwable $exception, Request $request): Response
{
    dump($request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->all())

    if ($request->headers->get('referer')) dump($exception, $request);
    return $this->render("commonoffice/error/test.html.twig", [
        'exception' => $exception
    ]);
}
```

And now the `dump` display `null`.

I've more or less understood that exceptions can sometimes create sub-requests which are probably the cause of the fact that I can't access flash messages.

If this is the case, is there anything I can do to change this behaviour?

I want to pass information from my HomeController to the ErrorController, is there any way of doing this (apart from using the exception message)?

I use an exception because it allows me to return a response with the correct HTTP code and I find it cleaner, but it may not be the best way in the end.

On the page, I want to display the exception message plus some “advices” to explain why it doesn't work (the flashbag with the 'info' key contains these “advices”).

I hope to be clear.

I have tried using the attributes of the request, accessing the session and flashbag directly via autowiring, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: I am not sure how it implemented in symfony but probably they use output buffer control to prevent all unnecessary output from showing, and only show data that returned from function. So you need to  use some variable instead dump, and pass it  same as you passed `'exception' => $exception` as second item in array, and then output it in twig.

Comment: instead of Request you could DI the [RequestStack](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.3/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RequestStack.php) instead off which you can access the main or parent request

Comment: @Sergey92zp The question was badly asked, it's not that the dump isn't working, it's rather that it's displaying null. I've edited my post.

Comment: @Jakumi Thanks to `RequestStack`, I can indeed access the previous request, but I still can't access the `FlashBag` because it's managed by the PHP session. So when it's deleted, it's deleted for good and for all past and future requests.
There are now two possibilities, it seems to me:
1. Use the previous request to store the information in the form of `attributes`.
2. Make my own `FlashBag` and save the info in the session and delete it once in the `ErrorController`.

Comment: then probably it is some sub-request, you can request flash message directly in your `commonoffice/error/test.html.twig` via `app.flashes('info')` View renders only once, so it will not request it twice.
About exception you can render simple view with custom response code like this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28883188/2590591

Comment: Since I'm slightly confused ... does the second dump still return `null` or now `[]`? if the latter: are you aware, that `FlashBag::all()` will *clear* the bag and `FlashBag::peekAll()` should be used instead? (just covering the bases, no offense). Because I would have imagined, that the session object, including all its bags, should still exist during the sub-request. I might be wrong though....